# GID in Tile Map

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

recently I am developing a game using Phaser.js, I have come to need my tile map objects and I have come to see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJZQabPyTHo).

The only problem is that the "sprites make objects" seeing this [example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/create-from-objects), this method is used map:

```
map.createFromObjects('Object Layer 1', 34, 'coin', 0, true, false, coins);
```

Where 34 is the "gid" ... How can I add this value to JSON? Because when creating the tilemap and objects, no object is assigned a "gid". Do I have to set it manually ._. ?

I use Tiled Map Editor Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@weastie Yes, it is an acceptable solution. However, if I have 20 or 100 objects could be torture. I have come to a solution and it is this and maybe you can serve you and to other than this at this juncture.

```
function create() {
  ...
  map = game.add.tilemap('map');
  map.addTilesetImage('ground_1x1');
  map.addTilesetImage('walls_1x2');
  map.addTilesetImage('tiles2');
  ...
  map.objects.Objects.forEach(function(element) {
     element.gid = 34;
  }, this); 
  ...   
  map.setCollisionBetween(1, 12);

  layer = map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1');

  layer.resizeWorld();
  map.createFromObjects('Object Layer 1', 34, 'coin', 0, true, false, coins);
 }
```

> map.objects

is the object that has the array of objects ("Object Layer 1"). All you have to do is access the array name and modify each object with a foreach. It is a simple way ...

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same problem. I don't know a good solution, but I've just been manually adding in the gid, by opening the .json file with a text editor. Look for something that says

```
"name":(Your object layer name),
"objects":[
   {
     first object properties...
   },
   {
     second object properties...
   }
```

Now, for each object that you want to assign a gid, add this text to the top of it's properties.

```
"gid":(Desired gid),
```

It is important that you put the comma at the end.
Here is an example of one:

```
 "name":"mainObjects",
 "objects":[
        {
         "gid":34,
         "height":32,
         "id":6,
         "name":"",
         "properties":
            {

            },
         "rotation":0,
         "type":"fire",
         "visible":true,
         "width":32,
         "x":352,
         "y":1248
        },
        {
         "gid":34,
         "height":32,
         "id":7,
         "name":"",
         "properties":
            {

            },
         "rotation":0,
         "type":"fire",
         "visible":true,
         "width":32,
         "x":384,
         "y":1248
        }],
```

Notice how for each object I added the "gid" property, and assigned it a value of 34, this value can be whatever you want though.

Now this will be annoying, because each time you export the tiled map, it removes the gid. Like I said, this isn't a great solution, but it will work until someone can respond with a better one.

Comment: Weird. I wonder where the original GID property came from? Tiled's old editor way back in the day? Thanks!